# Calling VB.Net from Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am trying to call a VB.Net subroutine on my ASP.Net page via a function key.  I have managed to detect the key press using a Javascript function and am now trying to call the VB.Net subroutine from Javascript.  I have seen 2 methods proposed, but have had no success with either:

1. Using jQuery
2. Using Web Methods

1) With jQuery, I get an error message in the web browser that says PageMethods undefined. 
I am using a ScriptManager with EnablePageMethods = “True” and have syntax “PageMethods.VBsubroutine() in the Javascript function, but it seems PageMethods is not recognised.

2) I have also declared the WebMethods as follows (for testing purposes):

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Sub ToggleTestButton()
    If btnTest.Text = “Alpha” Then
        btnTest.Text = “Omega” 
    Else
        btnTest.Text = “Alpha”
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Some have suggested that WebMethods should be declared as

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function xxx()
```

But I get an error with the control `btnTest.Text` being underlined. Something about having to create an instance of objects?  The issue is with the `Shared`.  Besides I’m not intending to get any output from the function, hence the use of Sub.

Some have suggested that it must be `Public Shared Function`.  Please advise on why this is so or if there is another way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

The webmethod route has no access to the elements on the page, and unless I'm mistaken should only be used when one requires to execute a sub asynchronously.

The best way to do this in my opinion would be be to place a hidden button on the page, then from the js that detects the function call, click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to call vb.net function on your asp.net server, when the user presses some key in his browser (client side)?

If yes, then you may try ajax.